# better way of sampling in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, sampling

I want 20 % of sample data from the input dataset.

I thought of 2 approaches:

1. Initially emitting 20 % data from each mapper (single mapper emits 20% of data).Then, the
   reducer finds 20 % of mapper data after shuffle and sort.(Same procedure applied for both Map and Reduce)
2. Simply emit each line from mapper and then find 20% of sample data from total data in Reducer.(processing only done is Reducer)

Which is the better approach?

Comment: I don't quite understand your first approach, can you rephrase it maybe?

Comment: I edited.Hope that makes clear.Else please ping me.

Comment: In case 1 if you apply same procedure on both map and reduce side then you will be sampling only 4% of the total data.In second case you will be sampling 20% of total data.Please think about that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely go with your first option.  I'm not sure why you need a reducer though.  Just filter out 20% in the map phase and call it a day.

Comment: but there will be as many output equal to number of mapper.Each mapper will be giving 20% of data

Comment: Yes there will be as many files as there are mappers, but each file is 20% of the data given to the mapper.  Not 20% of the entire dataset.